# Arbitrary File Overwrite, Dependency of truffle-hdwallet-provider

Tags: npm, truffle, erc20

I am trying to deploy a contract to mainnet, and after running "npm install --save dotenv truffle-hdwallet-provider" I get 1 high severity vulnerability - Arbitrary File Overwrite. (details below)

I have tried to open package-lock and edit versions of truffle-hdwallet, and also swarm-js to 4.4.8 but still getting the same error.

Solutions recommended on this thread (https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2625) is quite different I believe.

I get following [1 high severity vulnerability]:

```
Arbitrary File Overwrite 
Package: tar
Patched in: >=4.4.2 
Dependency of: truffle-hdwallet-provider  
Path: truffle-hdwallet-provider > web3 > web3-bzz > swarm-js > 
tar.gz > tar
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you find any solutions? having the same issue...